# Can a mock side_effect iterator be reset after it has been exhausted?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking

`mock.reset_mock()` will not reset a side effect iterator.  Is there a way to do this without creating the mock again?

```
>>> from mock import MagicMock
>>> mock = MagicMock(side_effect = [1,2])
>>> mock(), mock()
(1, 2)
>>> mock()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#114>", line 1, in <module>
    mock()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mock.py", line 955, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mock.py", line 1013, in _mock_call
    result = next(effect)
StopIteration
>>> mock.reset_mock()
>>> mock()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
StopIteration
>>> mock = MagicMock(side_effect = [1,2])
>>> mock(), mock()
(1, 2)
>>>
```

The intent is to re-use the mock in subsequent tests but I suspect that, like a generator, it cannot be *restarted*.

So (better late than never) after being pointed in the right direction I looked in `mock.py` and found that `side_effect` is an iterator object (which cannot be *reset* once exhausted):

```
def __set_side_effect(self, value):
    value = _try_iter(value)
    ...

def _try_iter(obj):
    ...
    try:
        return iter(obj)
    except TypeError:
        # XXXX backwards compatibility
        # but this will blow up on first call - so maybe we should fail early?
        return obj
```

and `def reset_mock()`  does not address the side efect.

Comment: How about passing infinite iterator? `mock = MagicMock(side_effect=itertools.cycle([1,2]))`; You don't need to call the `reset_mock`.

Comment: @falsetru: but if the mock is then used incorrectly the next call to the mock would give the wrong value.

Comment: Have you tried reassigning `side_effect`?

Comment: Reassigning the iterator was what I was looking for but using ```itertools.xyz``` for the side_effect will prove handy I suspect, thnx for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As user2357112 commented, reassigning `side_effect` will solve you problem.

```
>>> from mock import MagicMock
>>>
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> mock = MagicMock(side_effect=lst)
>>> mock(), mock()
(1, 2)
>>> mock.side_effect = lst  # <-------
>>> mock(), mock()
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of trying that.  You beat @user2357112 to the punch.

Answer (score 4):

Since Python 3.6, one can reset the mock's `side_effect` and `return_value` with:

```py
mock.reset_mock(return_value=True, side_effect=True)
```

This will:

- Revert the `return_value` to the mock's default
- Revert the `side_effect` to the mock's default of `None`.  It does *not* reset the `side_effect` iterator back to its beginning

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.reset_mock):

> In case you want to reset `return_value` or `side_effect`, then pass the corresponding parameter as `True`. Child mocks and the return value mock (if any) are reset as well.

Comment: For my simple example in the question this doesn't *reset* the side_effect so that it can be used again. It *removes* the side effect entirely. Make my example; print mock.side_effect; reset it; then print mock.side_effect again - you'll see that it is **gone**.

Comment: Just ran into what @wwii pointed out. The docs could do with some clarification here.

Comment: Admittedly, this does not answer the exact question, but mentioning that there is a `side_effect=True` option for resetting the mock is nonetheless very helpful. In my case, this answer unblocked me after I was literally stuck for hours with failing test cases.

Comment: Even though your response is correct according to the documentation, in my case it will raise an error as it doesn't accept `return_value` as an argument.