# How to reset mock iterator inside a for loop?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826180/can-a-mock-side-effect-iterator-be-reset-after-it-has-been-exhausted), but the answers in there are not adequate for what I'm doing.

I'm trying to test a method like this:

```
import mock


def stack_overflow_desired_output():
    print_a_few_times(['upvote', 'this', 'question!'])


def stack_overflow_mocked():
    the_mock = mock.Mock()
    the_mock.__iter__ = mock.Mock(return_value=iter(["upvote", "this", "question"]))
    print_a_few_times(the_mock)


def print_a_few_times(fancy_object):
    for x in [1, 2, 3]:
        for y in fancy_object:
            print("{}.{}".format(x, y))
```

When I call `stack_overflow_desired_output()` I get this:

```
1.upvote
1.this
1.question!
2.upvote
2.this
2.question!
3.upvote
3.this
3.question!
```

But when I call `stack_overflow_mocked()`, I get only get this:

```
1.upvote
1.this
1.question!
```

Is there a way to have that iterator reset itself whenever it's exhausted at the end of a for loop? Putting the reset inside of the `print_a_few_times`, function, [as described in the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826180/can-a-mock-side-effect-iterator-be-reset-after-it-has-been-exhausted), will be invasive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your mock object around the `__iter__` method of an actual list.

```
def stack_overflow_mocked():
    the_mock = mock.Mock()
    the_mock.__iter__ = mock.Mock(wraps=["upvote", "this", "question"].__iter__)
    print_a_few_times(the_mock)
```

Comment: That did it. You rock